# How to change the target framework from .NET Framework 4.5.2 to .NET Core 1.0 ? Is it feasible?

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio, asp.net-core, runtime

I have a web application which currently runs on .NET Framework 4.5.2. I want to test the application on .NET core. 
I have already installed .NET core 1.0 SDK
I know, there will be no complete portability but i want to know whether can i tweak the run time framework and check the behavior ? 
In Visual Studio 2015, how can i change my target framework to .NET core ?

Comment: Which type of web application it is - Webforms / MVC5 / ASP.NET core?

Comment: @Sanket It is a ASP.NET Web application(.NET Framework) with WebAPI template without Web Forms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can not target the same application to .NET Core platform directly. We have to do .NET core migration. 
I have used [.NET API Portability](https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnet-apiport) tool to check how much percentage of the code can be migrated to .NET core or any other .NET framework.
This tool gives us an overall idea of the assemblies available in .NET core to the assemblies that we are currently using in the application.